# Does anybody know why i am getting an error 528 on my bbc microbit V2.21?

Tags: bbc-microbit

I tried to update the firmware, and now i cant seem to get out of the error 528. Ive tried to downlead out of the box .hex, and microbit V2.21 newest firmware .hex, but no luck ):

i tried flashing microbit firmware again for v2.21 from microbit.org to my microbit while in maintenance mode, but i got a fail.txt file and still have error:  5, 2, 8, sad face.

Comment: Does the [info here](https://forums.pimoroni.com/t/microbit-v-2-21-error-code-528/22364) possibly help?

Comment: Oh yes! ! I have been trying to fix this for a long time now, i cant believe the answer was so simple. Thank you! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This support page from the micro:bit website lists a lot of the error codes and their meaning:
https://support.microbit.org/support/solutions/articles/19000016969-micro-bit-error-codes

For error code 528:

> The micro:bit has detected an unsupported update. This can occur if you attempt to flash a firmware .hex file whilst in normal MICROBIT mode. Try flashing a file created in one of the online editors to resolve the issue.

More info about the firmware.hex file can be found in the https://microbit.org/get-started/user-guide/firmware/ page. It's esentially a hex file used to update the "interface chip" (the microcontroller that handles all the USB features). That hex file is only meant to be flashed to the `MAINTENANCE` drive, which appears in "maintenance mode", and not into the "normal" `MICROBIT` drive where the user programme hex files are flashed.

If you flash any hex file created with the [MakeCode](https://makecode.microbit.org) or [Python Editor](https://python.microbit.org) into the `MICROBIT` drive it should clear the error code and run your programme.